# function calling in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have this couple of functions `wishList` and `remove_from_cart`. I want to call the 2nd function when the cart is successfully inserted into the `wishlist collection`. I tried doing that but I dont know the proper way and ending up with error.

```
function wishList(req, res, next) {
    db.cart.findOne({
        _id: mongoskin.helper.toObjectID(req.params._id)
    }, function(err, art) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        if (!art) {
            return res.status(404).send({
                status: '404 file not found'
            });
        }
        db.wishlist.insert({
            art_id: art._id,
            user_id: req.session.user._id
        }, function(err, result) {
            if (err) return next(err);
            res.send(result);
        })
    })
}

function remove_from_cart(req, res, next) {
    db.cart.findOne({
        _id: mongoskin.helper.toObjectID(req.params._id)
    }, function(err, art) {
        if (!art) {
            return res.status(400).send({
                status: '404 file not found'
            });
        }
        db.cart.remove({
            _id: mongoskin.helper.toObjectID(req.params._id)
        }, function(err, user) {
            if (err) return next(err);
            return res.status(400).send(
                ' The art has been removed from the cart '
            );
        });
    })
}
```

Comment: "ending up with error" — What error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling

```
res.send(result);
```

call

```
remove_from_card(req, res, function(err) { 
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.send(result)
})
```

Comment: thanks , i got to know where I was doing mistake  :)